# Javascript variable type (byte)

Tags: javascript, variables, types, byte

I searched for javascript byte type variables and I can't find byte type variable???

Thanks.

Comment: you can use an integer to simulate - a bit costly in terms of memory, but for anything you need to do in javascript, it would probably suffice

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There is no byte predefined type in javascript.

[click this link for Javascript types, detailed](http://www.mozilla.org/js/language/js20-2000-07/libraries/types.html)

the above link is dead, [here's a new one](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)

Answer (score 12):

JavaScript now supports raw binary data types (byte).

Look into [ArrayBuffer](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Typed_arrays).

Answer (score -2):

I think this is what you want:

```
var x = "A String"
var y = 42
alert("var x is " + typeof(x))
alert("var y is " + typeof(y))
```

This uses the javascript typeof() operator to detect what kind of type is variable x and y.

Comment: bro, that's not what he wants. You will never find the "byte" type in there